# How to change webcam resolution

Tags: webcam, cheese, zoom-meeting

In `zoom-client` (from snap) I can choose whether to use HD video or not, and turns out this setting persists when I close Zoom and open Cheese. It makes me think that this setting is global instead of zoom specific. Unfortunately Cheese doesn't have this setting, so that I need to open Zoom just to change this setting.

[image: Screenshot]

My question is, can I change webcam resolution without opening Zoom, probably via a terminal command line or a setting GUI (such as gnome settings)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just opened `Cheese` on ubuntu 20.04 to see if I could find this setting and I actually did.

If you click the icon at the top right corner that has 3 horizontal lines and then go to *Preferences* you will find two drop down settings, one for the *Photo Resolution* and the other one for the *Video Resolution* of your webcam.

If for some reason you cannot find those settings there, I will assume that you are using an external webcam that probably needs some third party software to tweak its settings. In that case, I suggest that you go to HP's website and search for you webcam's model specific software.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I found it, but it's still half of my question "probably via a terminal command line or a setting GUI", I meant such a gnome settings gui :D, so that I'm still waiting for other answer before accepting this answer. Or probably an answer such that "it's impossible because it's not a global setting".

Comment: When researching, I only saw people use third-party software for this matter so I concluded that probably there is no way to adjust your webcam settings other than installing a specific program for it or by the workaround we have spoken about (using the `Cheese` preferences).